# How to Filter Out Specific Value from API Generated Data in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[Filter Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVVUo.png)

As you can see above image, I just want to filter out only two specific value from API generated data using Python. I marked data in Red Sqaure box that I want to filter and generate total of
premium amount and brokerage. Here premium is my total profit of today and brokerage is charges.

One more image to understand the full code.
[Full API Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeR2t.png)

I want to generate specific value from available data in python.

Comment: Your question was not very clear. Do you have a DataFrame of that Json and you want to filter by those two fields?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I have added a full image of my code. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a simple dictionary, so:

```
data = api.get_limits()
premium = data['premium']
brokerage = data['brokerage']

print('premium:', premium)
print('brokerage:', brokerage)
```